# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory path issue when running MVC project

Tags: c#, file, stream

This code creates a log file in App_Data folder. If file doesn't exist it's created. It works when the MVC page is published on my IIS.

```
 var filename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + 
                "App_Data//" + 
                label + 
                DateTime.Now.ToString() + 
                ".txt";

 var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
```

However when i run the project local, i get :

> > NotSupportedException. the StreamWriter says that my path is not supported. This is the path im getting:

**"C:\Projects\x- chefsportalen 2.0\Chefsportalen\App_Data//Paragå manuell2015-05-18 11:00:18.txt"**

The App_Data folder exist and the path is correct, why am i getting this error?

Comment: ``"App_Data//""` should be ``@"App_Data\"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames are not allowed to contain the ":" character.

Use an explicit format string to specify a format that doesn't contain ":", e.g.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I'm not sure why it's working when you publish to IIS - maybe because IIS is using a culture that doesn't have ":" as time separator.